# Cross referencing Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, formulas, sumifs

I'm working with 3 worksheets.

PROJECTS consists of the following:

```
Project    ClientCode   Code     
------     ----------   ----     
Project1   ABC          123      
Project2   ABC          456      
Project3   DEF          789
```

INVOICES consists of:

```
ProjectCode   Amount
-----------   -----
123           $100
789           $200
123           $50
```

And CLIENTS consists of:

```
Code    Total
----    -----
ABC     [$150]
DEF     [$200]
```

I'm trying to create a formula which will populate the "Total" field on the client sheet by determining which invoices belong to which project belong to which client.  I feel like it would be a combination of SUMIF and LOOKUP, but I'm stumped.

EDIT: Revised the above to the format discussed below (swapped Projects column B and C)

Answer (score 0):

Using `VLOOKUP` and `SUMIF` in a single cell without any helper column is possible, but you will need to interchange the positions of columns `ClientCode` and `Code` in `PROJECTS` for it to work.

Interchange the column positions as mentioned above (so that `ClientCode` is before `Code`), then use:

```
=SUMIF(INVOICES!A:A, VLOOKUP(CLIENTS!A2, PROJECTS!B:C, 2, 0), INVOICES!B:B)
```

I'm assuming that row 1 of each worksheet has the column headers. `A2` here refers to `ABC`.

`VLOOKUP` first looks for the `Code` of the `ClientCode` and `SUMIF` then sums the amounts of matched `Code` in the `INVOICES` worksheet.

**EDIT:** Below should work better since `VLOOKUP` finds only the first match, which doesn't work here.

```
=SUM(SUMIF(INVOICES!A:A,IF(CLIENTS!A1=PROJECTS!C:C,PROJECTS!B:B),INVOICES!F:F))
```

Note that you have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to use this formula. After you did it for `ABC`, you can drag the formula to B. Also note that his formula can take some time to evaluate, and as such, it might be better if you change the ranges to an appropriate range. For example, if `INVOICES` has only 100 rows, change `INVOICES!A:A`, `INVOICES!B:B` to `INVOICES!A2:A100`, `INVOICES!B2:B100`, same goes for the other ranges in this formula.

Comment: I tried this (and thanks for the suggestion.)  It _almost_ does the job, the problem is that it's only totaling all invoices for the first project associated with the client, rather then all projects associated with them.  So if I add another row to "INVOICES" saying "456 / $75", this amount won't be reflected in the total.

Comment: @user2406594 Okay, sorry about that. I edited my answer to incorporate this. It might be a little slow, but that's because the formula can be said to be evaluating a lot of `vlookups`. I already mentioned how you can speed this up a bit.